# WiX Installer with Visual C++ Redistributable install per user

Tags: c++, installation, wix, redistributable

I'm using Wix to generate an msi installer file for a project. I'm using wix to also install the Visual C++ Redistributable files (Following this guide: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_vcredist.htm )

Although I specify InstallScope="perUser", my installer is still trying to install for all users. This wasn't happening until I added the redistributable file.

I have also added

```
<Property Id="ALLUSERS" Secure="yes"/>
```

with no luck.

It seems the merge of VCRedist is causing the need for privilege escalation.

Is there any way to generate an installer that installs with Visual C++ Redistributable per user (ie not for all users)?

Comment: Which version of Windows? I'm guessing this is for Windows 7? Also, from previous experience, merge modules tend to suck. Detect if the redist is installed and shout at the user to get it themselves :) Makes your life far easier too.

Comment: Yeah Windows 7. Just curious, what kind of troubles did you run into with merge modules?

Comment: Mainly performance issues - very slow to install compared with just running the redist msi and the progress bar wouldn't update for a long time because of it (which always looks like something's wrong IMO). Haven't used WiX in a while, so I'm not sure if there have been any updates to the merge modules or MSI v5.0 to address them though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the Visual C++ runtime DLLs are installed under the Windows directory, so administrator privileges are required to install them. You can install the DLLs locally and not require administrator privileges ; for example, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293565.aspx.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks Bob